# How to get a the value of "background-color" property of an element that I have in my NATIVE App

Tags: c#, appium

I'm developing a test code in c# (v3.0.02 of Appium) and I need to get the value of "background-color" property of an element that I have in my NATIVE App.

Here is a part of the code:

```
ReadOnlyCollection obj = driver.FindElementsByName("lblProtocolo");

for(int i=0;i<obj.Count;i++)
{
var str = obj[i].GetCssValue("background-color");
}
```

but is throwing an exception:

```
Test method ASEXamarin.Shared.Tests.TelaInicial.TesteRows threw exception: 
System.NotImplementedException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html
```

There is any form to get this property in NATIVE Apps?

There is a related post in: 
[Appium Android UI testing - how to verify the style attribute of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164413/appium-android-ui-testing-how-to-verify-the-style-attribute-of-an-element/43187007?noredirect=1#comment73447089_43187007)

Comment: GetCssValue is only for webapp not native. Try with get_attribute(). If not working then ask Developer provide the details in accessibility parameter(https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-get-text-color-in-android-native-app/229) , hope this will help you.

Comment: @arulchristopher thanks for your answer! I'll ask about this with the dev...Because I tried get the color property with getAttribute but doesn't worked .